# Can't access element inside slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using Slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I'm trying to get the id of the element I change. The following code obviously works outside the slick slider, but for some odd reason it always returns the first element of the slider.

```
        <div class="container-slide">
          <div class="slider slider-category">
            <div class="slider-card">
                <div class="row block-image">
                    <div class="background-upload">
                        <label for="image">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"></i>
                        </label>

                        <input id="image" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="image" class="text-center image-card" data-id="1"/> 
                    </div>                      
                </div>     

          </div>

            <div class="slider-card">
                <div class="row block-image">
                    <div class="background-upload">
                        <label for="image">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"></i>
                        </label>

                        <input id="image" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="image" class="text-center image-card" data-id="2"/> 
                    </div>                      
                </div>     

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


 $('.image-card').on('change', function() {
   console.log($(this).data('id'));

 });
```

The previous jquery code gives me always "1" as result. So it gets only the first element.
Why is this happening?
Without using slick slider, it's obviously working fine, there shound't be anything wrong with that very simple code...

Am I missing something about slick slider? I read everything and all the documentation but I couldn't find anything for this issue. I also tried beforeChange event, but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: That JQuery code seems to work when put into a JSFiddle.

Comment: Have you added slickslider js? May I see your jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out the problem!

I don't know why but the id and the label were affecting the on change.

So if I change the code into this:

```
    <div class="container-slide">
      <div class="slider slider-category">
        <div class="slider-card">
            <div class="row block-image">
                <div class="background-upload">
                    <label for="image">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"></i>
                    </label>

                    <input id="image" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="image" class="text-center image-card" data-id="1"/> 
                </div>                      
            </div>     

      </div>

        <div class="slider-card">
            <div class="row block-image">
                <div class="background-upload">
                    <label for="image2">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"></i>
                    </label>

                    <input id="image2" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="image" class="text-center image-card" data-id="2"/> 
                </div>                      
            </div>     

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

It works fine. (I changed the input id and label for into "image2).